# Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: POSTMAN

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate, postman

I am trying to hit a server running on port 8080 of an AWS EC2 instance with a POST request.

This is the response that POSTMAN gives me when I send the request:

> Error: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host:
> some-address.compute.amazonaws.com. is not in the cert's altnames:
> DNS:chat.my-app.app

I tried looking for it but this seems to be a NodeJS and certificates issue.

I am not using Node and I don't know what to do with certificates? (I don't know much about how or why I would need them), but I have .pem file which helped me SSH into the EC2 instance.

How can I resolve this error in Postman?

Also, if it matters, it is a Graphql request.

Comment: Are you using API gateway

Comment: It's just a simple server running on a new EC2. So no NGINX or anything like that.

Comment: You cannot create a cname pointing to amazon generated public dns name. Can you confirm thatswhat you are doing. Create an A record pointing to your IP address

Comment: Do I do that from the AWS console?

Comment: are you trying to access the website over https such as https://chat.my-app.app ?

Comment: not https. Doing it through http. http://ec2-3-7-109-135.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/

Answer (score 17):

You need to turn off SSL Certificate verification in Postman's settings.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I had the same problem with `wscat` and solved it by adding `--no-check`switch after reading your answer

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you have created a dns name pointing to the AWS generated public dns name for ec2 instance. It's not the correct way. You need to setup an `A` record and point it to the public ip address of the ec2 instance.

When you have a CNAME created against the EC2 generated public dns name (chat.my-app.app) and access the URL over SSL (https://chat.my-app.app), the process (possibly nginx in your case) that listens to the HTTPS port (usually 443) will check whether the domain name that you used (chat.my-app.app) is listed as one of alternate domains listed in the SSL certificate that the amazon generated dns name uses.

Comment: This helps, thanks! I was facing the same issue and changing the /etc/hosts entries to get rid of those pointing solved my issue

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue and tried to add the Host in the header and it works.
Host:EC2 generated public DNS name (chat.my-app.app)